# Пересечение временных интервалов MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы с началом и концом временных промежутков. Необходимо определить время, которое было между этими временными интервалами - например, 10 - 16 и 9 - 15 => 10 - 15. Я решил данную задачу через декартово произведение, однако уверен, что это решение можно улучшить
В примере таблица tbl1 отображает статусы сотрудника (где B - рабочий статус), а таблица tbl2 - рабочее и нерабочее время сотрудника (где Work - рабочий статус). `NULL` же означает, что временной интервал ещё не закрыт и все ещё продолжается.

UPD: Таблицы изначально имели только статус и время изменения, в такой вид я их привел с помощью `LEAD(TimeChange) OVER (ORDER BY TimeChange)`

```
DECLARE @time_now time = CAST(GETDATE() AS time)
;WITH tbl1 AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES 
        ('A', '00:04:05', '00:09:05'),
        ('B', '00:09:05', '00:30:02'),
        ('A', '00:30:02', '04:02:22'),
        ('B', '04:02:22', NULL)
    ) X(Status, StatusStart, StatusStop)
),
tbl2 AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('Work', '00:00:00', '00:22:02'),
        ('NoWork', '00:22:02', '05:02:22'),
        ('Work', '05:02:22', NULL)
    ) X(Work, WorkStart, WorkStop)
)

SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, 
        IIF(WorkStart > StatusStart, WorkStart, StatusStart) AS TimeStart,
        ISNULL(IIF(WorkStop < StatusStop, WorkStop, StatusStop), @time_now) AS TimeStop
    FROM tbl1, tbl2
    WHERE tbl1.[Status] = 'B' 
        AND tbl2.[Work] = 'Work' 
        AND WorkStart < ISNULL(StatusStop, @time_now) 
        AND ISNULL(WorkStop, @time_now) > StatusStart
) t1
```

Comment: *Я решил данную задачу через декартово произведение* Ничто не мешает превратить его в честный JOIN, если часть условий, логически отвечающих за связывание (да хоть все! хотя как по мне - то два последних) переместить из WHERE в ON. *уверен, что это решение можно улучшить* А существует ли реальная необходимость в улучшении (не синтаксическом, которое описано выше)?

Comment: Повлияет ли JOIN на производительность? 
У меня довольно большие таблицы tbl1 и tbl2, там сотни тысяч строк и улучшение поможет снизить нагрузку на сервер.
В итоге мне нужно просто количество минут TimeStop - TimeStart

Comment: *Повлияет ли JOIN на производительность?* 99% за то, что план не изменится ни на байт. *У меня довольно большие таблицы tbl1 и tbl2, там сотни тысяч строк и улучшение поможет снизить нагрузку на сервер.* Э/ту проблему надо решать правильным индексированием. Чему ну очень помешает наличие NULL и соответственно необходимость использования функций при связывании. Возможно, если количество записей с NULL не очень велико, имеет смысл отдельно обработать записи с NULL и без, а потом UNION ALL/

Comment: Я до этого преобразую данные, у меня в самом начале таблица без NULL, но и без окончания интервала, то есть просто TimeChange и статус. К такому виду я её привожу через `LEAD(TimeChange) OVER`

Comment: А сразу навесить ISNULL, чтобы не заниматься этим при связывании? впрочем, это всё равно динамический набор, индексы считай побоку...

Comment: Индексы есть на TimeChange на обоих таблицах, но да, при вот таком связывании после `LEAD()` там уже неважно

Comment: _имеет смысл отдельно обработать записи с NULL и без_. Логически таблицы никак не связаны, в одной может быть NULL значение 30 дней назад,  а в другой - 5 минут назад. Однако, NULL значение там только одно - последнее по TimeStart (или по TimeChange)

Comment: [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49832899/5741205) пробовали?

Comment: @MaxU, там описано нахождение пересекающихся интервалов в пределах одной таблицы, в моем случае у меня две таблицы, в которых по отдельности гарантируется отсутствие пересечений

Comment: @MaxU, а, понял. Да там суть в самом популярном ответе та-же, разница только в INNER JOIN и в EXISTS

Comment: *в моем случае у меня две таблицы, в которых по отдельности гарантируется отсутствие пересечений* Классическая фраза: формулируйте задачу, а не (только) свои попытки её решить. Так что давайте от печки. Выкладывайте CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц (таблицы - честные, а не временные или декларированные), INSERT INTO с примером данных (или можете прямо сразу создать online fiddle), требуемый результат для этих данных, и подробные пояснения, почему именно так. И версию сервера точную укажите на всякий случай.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/afad9e/2. Версия 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основная проблема *(на больших объёмах данных)* у авторского запроса в том, что он выполняется за время `O(n^2)`, т.к. при обработке каждой записи 1-й таблицы он будет читать вторую таблицу целиком. *(здесь и далее, буду считать, что обе таблицы содержат одинаковое число строк, равное `n`)*

Условия вида `WorkStart < ISNULL(StatusStop, @time_now)` особо не помогают - даже если бы такое условие "ходило" по индексу, то в среднем случае читало бы не всю 2-ю таблицу, а её половину - и это всё тот же `O(n^2)`.

В данной задаче мало способов уменьшить оценку запроса. Наиболее простой из них: ускорить выборку подходящих записей из 2-й таблицы (мы же **знаем**, что на самом деле их очень **мало**). В этом могут помочь такие реализации соединения таблиц, как `Hash Join` и `Merge Join`. Но чтобы задействовать любое из них, в запросе нужна колонка, по которой будем выполнять условие равенства, по типу такого `tbl1.Hash_Column = tbl2.Hash_Column`. И чем меньше записей приходится на каждое отдельное значение данного столбца, тем лучше.

Где возьмём дополнительный столбец? Да просто вычислим в запросе. К требованию селективности вполне подойдёт начальная дата интервала с вырезанным из неё временем.

Теперь, выборка из каждой исходной таблицы может выглядеть примерно так:

```
Select
    Hash_Date = Cast(Time_Begin as date),
    Time_Begin, Time_End = IsNull(Time_End, @time_now)
From
(
    Select
        Time_Begin = TimeChange,
        Time_End = Lead(TimeChange) Over (Order By TimeChange),
        Status_Begin = [Status],
        Status_End = Lead([Status]) Over (Order By TimeChange)
    From
        dbo.tbl1
) t
Where ( Status_Begin = 1 ) and ( IsNull(Status_End, 1) = 0 )
```

К сожалению, при таком подходе появляется проблема: что, если интервал начинается в один день, а заканчивается в другой? Да, всё правильно - если во второй таблице соответствующий интервал и начинается, и заканчивается в "другой" день, то мы эту пару интервалов потеряем.

На самом деле проблема решаемая. В описании задачи - учёт рабочего времени, следовательно разница дат в любом случае будет невелика (даже если система учёта засбоила и несколько записей в таблице были утеряны). Так что, можем без особых потерь размножить подобные записи по количеству дней на интервале, и пусть значение `Hash_Column` принимает все возможные значения даты из интервала.

Допустим, в 1-й таблице имеется интервал `2020-03-01 22:00` - `2020-03-03 05:10`. В этом случае выборка должна будет содержать 3 записи:

```
Hash_Column / Time_Start / Time_End
2020-03-01 / 2020-03-01 22:00 / 2020-03-03 05:10
2020-03-02 / 2020-03-01 22:00 / 2020-03-03 05:10
2020-03-03 / 2020-03-01 22:00 / 2020-03-03 05:10
```

Теперь, с какой бы из 3-х возможных дат ни начинался соответствующий интервал во 2-й таблице, мы сможем поймать их по равенству колонки `Hash_Column`.

Остался только один вопрос: что, если в обеих таблицах соответствующие интервалы длятся по нескольку дней, ведь результаты будут множиться (дубли строк)? Ну это, если честно, вообще не проблема - либо махнуть рукой и написать `distinct` на результат соединения, либо добавить в соединении дополнительное условие на колонку `Hash_Column` - чтобы она попадала либо на начальную дату интервала из 1-й таблицы, либо на начальную дату интервала из 2-й таблицы.

Ну вот, вроде всё учтено, размножим строки с помощью рекурсивного CTE и получим итоговый запрос:

```
Declare @time_now datetime = getdate();

With
intervals_1 As
(
    Select
        Hash_Date = Cast(Time_Begin as date),
        Time_Begin, Time_End = IsNull(Time_End, @time_now)
    From
    (
        Select
            Time_Begin = TimeChange,
            Time_End = Lead(TimeChange) Over (Order By TimeChange),
            Status_Begin = [Status],
            Status_End = Lead([Status]) Over (Order By TimeChange)
        From
            dbo.tbl1
    ) t
    Where ( Status_Begin = 1 ) and ( IsNull(Status_End, 1) = 0 )

    Union All

    Select DateAdd(dd, 1, Hash_Date), Time_Begin, Time_End
    From intervals_1
    Where ( Hash_Date < Cast(Time_End as date) )
),

intervals_2 As
(
    Select
        Hash_Date = Cast(Time_Begin as date),
        Time_Begin, Time_End = IsNull(Time_End, @time_now)
    From
    (
        Select
            Time_Begin = TimeChange,
            Time_End = Lead(TimeChange) Over (Order By TimeChange),
            Status_Begin = [Status],
            Status_End = Lead([Status]) Over (Order By TimeChange)
        From
            dbo.tbl2
    ) t
    Where ( Status_Begin = 1 ) and ( IsNull(Status_End, 1) = 0 )

    Union All

    Select DateAdd(dd, 1, Hash_Date), Time_Begin, Time_End
    From intervals_2
    Where ( Hash_Date < Cast(Time_End as date) )
)

Select
    TimeStart = IIf(t1.Time_Begin >= t2.Time_Begin, t1.Time_Begin, t2.Time_Begin),
    TimeStop = IIf(t1.Time_End <= t2.Time_End, t1.Time_End, t2.Time_End)
From
    intervals_1 t1
    Inner Hash Join intervals_2 t2 On
        ( t1.Hash_Date = t2.Hash_Date )
Where
    ( t1.Time_Begin <= t2.Time_End ) and ( t2.Time_Begin <= t1.Time_End ) and
    ( t1.Hash_Date In ( Cast(t1.Time_Begin as date), Cast(t2.Time_Begin as date) ) )
```

Когда в таблицах `tbl1` и `tbl2` по 1 миллиону строк, данный запрос у меня отрабатывает за 8-10 секунд.

Схему таблиц создал авторским скриптом: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/afad9e/2

Для заполнения таблиц тестовыми данными использовал следующий скрипт:

```
Set NoCount On;

Declare
    @rec_count int = 500000,
    @i int,
    @dt datetime;

Truncate Table dbo.tbl1;
Truncate Table dbo.tbl2;

Set @i = 0;
Set @dt = '20100101 10:00:00';

While ( @i < @rec_count )
Begin
    Insert Into dbo.tbl1 ( TimeChange, [Status] )
    Values ( @dt, 1 );

    Set @dt = dateadd(ss, 360 + 360 * 7 * rand(), @dt);

    Insert Into dbo.tbl1 ( TimeChange, [Status] )
    Values ( @dt, 0 );

    Set @dt = dateadd(ss, 360 * 15 + 360 * 2 * rand(), @dt);
    Set @i = @i + 1;
End;

Set @i = 0;
Set @dt = '20100101 10:00:00';

While ( @i < @rec_count )
Begin
    Insert Into dbo.tbl2 ( TimeChange, [Status] )
    Values ( @dt, 1 );

    Set @dt = dateadd(ss, 360 + 360 * 7 * rand(), @dt);

    Insert Into dbo.tbl2 ( TimeChange, [Status] )
    Values ( @dt, 0 );

    Set @dt = dateadd(ss, 360 * 15 + 360 * 2 * rand(), @dt);
    Set @i = @i + 1;
End;
```

Comment: Понял - идея в том, чтобы соединять даты, а не размытые условия сравнения `datetime`

Comment: Да, именно так. Соединяем по равенству дат, затем "шлифуем" полной версией условия на пересечение диапазонов. Что насчёт быстродействия запроса, устраивает оно в данном варианте? В принципе, тут ещё можно переписать парой курсоров, с которыми на индексах будет честный `O(n)`, но у меня это отрабатывает немного дольше цельного запроса. Наверное, для преимущества в производительности на курсоре должны быть объёмы данных на порядки больше миллиона строк.

Comment: Забавно получилось) Я переписал код на свои реалии, где я внутри каждой таблицы произвожу фильтрацию, так вот, при INNER JOIN я получаю план выполнения с HASH INNER JOIN и двумя NONCLUSTERED INDEX SEEK, но когда я добавляю хинт INNER HASH JOIN - получаю два INDEX SCAN

Comment: Действительно, забавненько вышло... У меня, на тестовых таблицах, такого эффекта не было: что с хинтом `HASH`, что без него - план был одинаковым (конечно, на достаточно больших объёмах данных). Наверное, на "боевых" таблицах у Вас есть ещё какие-то столбцы и индексы с их участием. А что по быстродействию обоих вариантов?

Comment: Без хинта - меньше 3-х секунд. С хинтом - больше 2-х минут. Причем без хинта план и так идет с HASH JOIN. Как вариант - темповые таблицы можно

Comment: Берите тот вариант, который быстрее (без хинта), зачем тут темповые таблицы городить. Но попробуйте ещё в индекс включить (INCLUDE) колонку `Status` - быть может, этим удастся убрать из плана сортировку на запросе с хинтом.